# Log4J RollingFileAppender doesn't roll files when creating two appenders to the same file

Tags: java, logging, log4j, rollingfileappender

Although I've read multiple other questions and answers regarding this issue, I didn't find the answer and would appreciate any help.

```
public static void rerouteAppenderToFile(File file, Logger... log) {
    for (Logger logger : log) {
        rerouteAppenderToFile(file, logger);
    }
}

public static void rerouteAppenderToFile(File file, Logger log) {
    log.setAdditivity(false);
    log.setLevel(Level.DEBUG);
    RollingFileAppender fa = new RollingFileAppender();
    fa.setName("RollingFileAppender_" + log.getName());
    fa.setMaxBackupIndex(3);
    fa.setMaxFileSize("20MB");
    File folder = file.getParentFile();
    folder.mkdirs();
    if (folder.exists() && folder.isDirectory()) {
        fa.setFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
        fa.setLayout(new PatternLayout(LOGGER_PATTERN));
        fa.setThreshold(Level.DEBUG);
        fa.setAppend(true);
        fa.activateOptions();
        log.addAppender(fa);
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve here is being able to append multiple loggers (2 or more) to the same file using a RollingFileAppender. For some reason the files aren't rolled and the logs keep getting larger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you create multiple `RollingFileAppender`s that write to the same file.

So even if one `RollingFileAppender` tries to roll over to a new file it cannot do so, since the file is locked by the other `RollingFileAppender`s.

What you could do is to create only one `RollingFileAppender` instance and reroute the loggers to this single instance.

The following code gives the idea, but it won't work if you call `rerouteAppenderToFile()` several times for a single file.

```
public static void rerouteAppenderToFile(File file, Logger... log) {
    RollingFileAppender fa = createAppender(file);
    for (Logger logger : log) {
        rerouteAppenderToFile(f, logger);
    }
}

public static Appender createAppender(File file) {
    RollingFileAppender fa = new RollingFileAppender();
    fa.setName("RollingFileAppender_" + log.getName());
    fa.setMaxBackupIndex(3);
    fa.setMaxFileSize("20MB");
    File folder = file.getParentFile();
    folder.mkdirs();
    fa.setFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
    fa.setLayout(new PatternLayout(LOGGER_PATTERN));
    fa.setThreshold(Level.DEBUG);
    fa.setAppend(true);
    fa.activateOptions();
    return fa;
}

public static void rerouteAppenderToFile(Appender fa, Logger log) {
    log.setAdditivity(false);
    log.setLevel(Level.DEBUG);
    log.addAppender(fa);
}
```